# Using image in boostrap carousel other than background for slide

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I am trying to use an image in the bootstrap carousel just as text like one heading on the left side image in the middle and second heading on the right side as I have in the attached image.Attached image as expected carousel what I need:

[image]

But when I try it on the bootstrap carousel I have the image going down from the carousel body. What I have done is that I have assigned the carousel a height of 500px and placing then centering the carousel with absolute positioning

```
.carousel{
  position: absolute;
     top: 0;
     bottom: 0;
     left: 0;
     right: 0;
     width: 50%;
     height: 30%;
     margin: auto;
}
```

its working all good with the text but when i add the image it again changes it position and goes down the frame.as attached in the image what i am getting:

[image]

I want to bring it back up

my html code is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="js/bootstrap/bootstrap.js"></script>
  <!--  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,500,600,700,800,900" rel="stylesheet">-->
  </head>
  <body>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row header flex-container">
    <div class="sidebar-header">

    </div>
    <div class="main-bg">
      <div class="row">
        <nav>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li class="get-quote"><a href="#">Get quote</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="main-slider">
          <div class="container-fluid">

            <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
              <!-- Indicators -->
              <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active">01</li>
                <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1">02</li>
                <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2">03</li>
              </ol>

              <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
              <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="item active">
                  <img class="slider-height" src="img/bag.png">
                </div>


              </div>

              <!-- Left and right controls -->

            </div>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>

  </body>
</html>
```

my css is

```
.main-slider{
  height: 500px;
  text-align: center;

position: relative;
  max-height: 100%;
  background-color: #FFD731;
}
.carousel{
  position: absolute;
     top: 0;
     bottom: 0;
     left: 0;
     right: 0;
     width: 50%;
     height: 30%;
     margin: auto;
}
.carousel-indicators {
    position: absolute;

    left: 150%;
    z-index: 15;

    text-align: center;
    list-style: none;
}
.carousel-indicators li {
    display:block;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    margin: 10px;
    text-indent:0px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: #000 \9;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    border: none;
    border-radius: none;
}
.carousel-indicators .active {
    width: inherit;
    height: inherit;
    margin: inherit;
    background-color:transparent;
}
```

Comment: Can you add all of your code for your carousel and also the styles? Otherwise we would have to guess what the problem is.

Comment: done sir updated the code,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if it's part of your example code and that you've remove other slides, but you have three indicators, but only one slide. That can cause some trouble. So I would start by replacing this:

```
<div class="item active">
  <img class="slider-height" src="img/bag.png">
</div>
<div class="item">
  <img class="slider-height" src="img/ANOTHER-IMAGE.png">
</div>
<div class="item">
  <img class="slider-height" src="img/A-THIRD-IMAGE.png">
</div>
```

It's just so you don't experience some wierd behaviour because of this, when you're trying to solve another problem.

---

### The solution to your actual question

This would be to position the image in the center-center of `item`. Uhh... Hang on! Shouldn't `item` be `carousel-item` ([ref](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/carousel/#slides-only))? Otherwise the styling might mess up?

Never the less... I would add this css to solve it:

```
.item, 
.carousel-item {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

It's using [Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) to position the image in the center-center of the image.

I hope I understood your question correctly.

Comment: it still has no effect because its not the carousel item that needs to align its children, actually when I add the image. the whole item comes down but space is in the main carousel. I hope that you get me

Comment: I'm not sure if I get you. Do you mean that the image is bottom-aligned instead of center-aligned? If so, then the code I posted should fix it?

Comment: I found the solution actually to centre the carousel inside the yellow box i restricted its width and height by percentage in the css so due to image  size it was going down so but removing it all fixed